# Convert .fbx model into animatable model for unity

Tags: blender

import bpy

## Import the .fbx model.

model = bpy.data.objects.load("model.fbx")

## Add an armature to the scene.

armature = bpy.data.armatures.new("MyArmature")

## Parent the .fbx model to the armature.

model.parent = armature

## Pose the armature to create the desired animation.

## ...

## Export the armature and .fbx model to Unity.

bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath="animation.fbx")

AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'load'

Please help me fix this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script that you copy pasted from online article doesnt really add anything to your question. Does your model even have all the required features? Just follow this [link](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/animation/armatures/index.html?highlight=armature#armatures) and understand all the requirements.

I am assuming this is your first time running a script in blender. I dont recommend doing that unless you know what exactly everything does